# Python window focus

Tags: python, gtk, focus, pygtk, xlib

I would like to find out if a window has focus. I am using pyGTK and would be helpful to us that but have got some Xlib in my script as well.

I've used:

```
self.window.add_events( gdk.FOCUS_CHANGE_MASK )
self.window.connect("focus-in-event", self.helloworld)
```

but this gives me the event every time the window is being focused in, even if it is already focused. I want it to tell me just if it isn't focused before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether a window is active using the [`is-active`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWindow.html#GtkWindow--is-active) property. Connect to `notify::is-active` to get a notification when the property value changes.

Example:

```
def is_active_changed(window, param):
    print window.props.is_active
window.connect('notify::is-active', is_active_changed)
```